# Android bound service - order of onServiceConnected() and startCommand()

Tags: android, binding

In my app, I'm bounding to a non-existing service by calling `bindService()`, and later I create the service using `startService()`.

In the bound services [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services#Lifecycle), it says that `onBind()` and `onStartCommand()` can be called in any order.

What about `onServiceConnected()`? Is there an order guaranteed between it and `onStartCommand()`?

Comment: If you are using a bound service, you shouldn't call `startService` anymore!

Comment: @aminography what do you mean? If you're calling `bindService()` with flags=0, the service won't be started and you can start it later with `startService`